# How can I define templatefield with check box in ASP.NET with programming?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, templatefield

I want to define a template field with a checkbox on a grid view in asp.net
like this:

```
TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
tf.ItemTemplate = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox();
gridView1.Columns.Add(tf);
```

but this error appears:

> cannot implicitly convert 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' to 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate'.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that like this

> on your grid load event

```
tfield = new TemplateField();
tfield.HeaderText = "CheckBox";
GridView1.Columns.Add(tfield);
```

> on your Row Databound

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
 chk.ID = "chk";
 chk.Text = "View";
 // chk.CheckedChanged=event Name  you can add an event here
e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(chk);
```